# Prove that if $R[x]$ is a PID, then $R$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I just need someone to check my proof and provide me feedback:

Since $R[x]$ is a PID, then the ideal $I = (x-1)$ generated by the polynomial $x-1$ is maximal because it is of degree 1 added to a constant.

So $R[x]/I\simeq R$ is a field, so $R$ is a field.

---

Is this proof enough/correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, looks good (you could also just take the ideal generated by $x$).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. It is a different proof than the linked duplicate.