# Prove that if $I$ is maximal, then $R[X]$ is a PID.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity such that $R[X]$ is a UFD. Denote the ideal $\langle X\rangle $ by $I$.

Prove that

- If $I$ is maximal, then $R[X]$ is a PID.
- If $R[X]$ is a Euclidean Domain then $I$ is maximal.
- If $R[X]$ is a PID then it is a ED.

We know that $R[X]/\langle X\rangle \cong R$. Since $I$ is maximal then $R$ is a field. Also every field is a Euclidean Domain and hence a PID and also a UFD.

By Gauss Lemma $R[X]$ is a UFD.

But these facts are not helping anything in these statements to prove.

Please give some hints.

Comment: Have you tried using the main property of an Euclidean domain, i.e. the Euclidean algorithm? It'll be slightly harder since you don't *know* a priori that the norm is the degree (and it might not be, norms are quite "flexible" in some well-defined sense)  but it still allows you to come to the same conclusion.

Comment: A hint for $(3)$: try proving $R$ is a field, whence the result follows. To do so, consider the ideal $I_{r} := \langle r, X \rangle$ for any nonzero element $r \in R$; try to use the fact that $I_{r}$ is principal to prove that $r$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These results are somewhat straightforward with this result:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$. The following are equivalent.

1. $R$ is a field.
2. $R[X]$ is a Euclidean domain.
3. $R[X]$ is a P.I.D.

   1. $\Rightarrow$ 2. is a standard result.
   2. $\Rightarrow$ 3. follows from the result that says "Euclidean domains are P.I.D.'s"
   3. $\Rightarrow$ 1.: Suppose $R[X]$ is a P.I.D; the ideal $(X)$ is a prime ideal in $R[X]$ because $R[X]/(X) \cong R$ is an integral domain ($R$ is subring of the integral domain $R[X]$). Moreover, nonzero prime ideals in a P.I.D. are maximal, so $(X)$ is maximal in $R[X]$. Thus $R[X]/(X) \cong R$ is a field.

Now your statements should follow immediately.

[Note 3. $\Rightarrow$ 1. can be proved using the definition of a field, as hinted by @Alex Wertheim in the comments, but it is a little longer...]

Comment: +1 Nice! That's much slicker than the argument I noted in the comments.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Are you referring to [this proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733335/prove-that-if-rx-is-a-pid-then-r-is-a-field?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Answer (score 3):

The first part is easy. We have $R[X]/I=R[X]/\langle X\rangle\cong R$. We are given that $I$ is maximal. So $R[X]/I$ is a field. Hence $R$ is a field. So $R[X]$ is an ED, and hence a PID.

Comment: Which one is "the first part"? Moreover, the OP has already mentioned this case, don't you think?